# User not able to post iframes in joomla article

Tags: iframe, joomla, joomla3.5, joomla-content-editor

I am not able to add iframes to an article as a limited user.

As a super user, I am able to do so because I allowed it in the JCE editor settings. There is an option for user profiles there, so I edited the default one and gave permission to every user. Still when I login as a user with limited rights (no admin rights and no superuser rights) it refuses to save the iframe.

What am I doing wrong?

I am use JCE in Joomla 3.5.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed this steps **`set Filter Type to No Filtering`** in Joomla! **Global Configuration**, **Text Filters tab**

**Configure Joomla! Article filters**

By default Joomla!  'cleans' content on saving, removing script tags, event attributes (such as `onclick, onmouseover` etc.) and style tags.

A simple article parameter change is all that is required to fix this.

Joomla! 2.5 and Joomla! 3

1. In the Joomla! Global Configuration, click on the Text Filters tab.
2. For the Super Users group, or any other trusted user group, set Filter Type to No Filtering. Make sure that you only set this option for user groups that can be trusted as setting the Filter Type to No Filtering will essentially allow the user to include any html in an article.

Reference https://www.joomlacontenteditor.net/support/faq/item/iframe-removed-on-saving

Answer (score 2):

> Joomla! 2.5 and Joomla! 3

1. In the Joomla! Global Configuration, click on the Text Filters tab.
2. For the Super Users group, or any other trusted user group, set
   Filter Type to No Filtering. Make sure that you only set this option
   for user groups that can be trusted as setting the Filter Type to No
   Filtering will essentially allow the user to include any html in an
   article.

Please refer this url
https://www.joomlacontenteditor.net/support/faq/item/iframe-removed-on-saving

Comment: Thanks, it worked, someone answered a little earlier though.

Answer (score 0):

Also, in case there is still trouble with this after trying the above solution, make sure that the embed code's URL is set to whatever the site's SSL setting is.

For instance, if the site is set to Force SSL in the configuration.php document in the root folder and your site is https as a result, the URL of the embed code needs to also be https. Browsers such as Firefox will block the iframe if the URL is http.

For what it's worth. Cheers!